# Socket.receive executing only once

Tags: java

DatagramSocket receiving only first packet.

As you can see, I created infinite loop, which should be sending typed text back.
I am receiving back only first line - where is the problem?

(connect is command of my remote server)

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    try {
        main.setupConnection(InetAddress.getByName("145.239.92.199"), 6969, "Szuja");
        main.socket = new DatagramSocket();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            main.wyslijPakiet(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private DatagramSocket socket;
private InetAddress adresKonsultantow;
private int port;

private void setupConnection(InetAddress adress, int port, String nickname) {
    this.adresKonsultantow = adress;
    this.port = port;
    if(socket != null)
        socket.close();
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.connect(adresKonsultantow, port);
    } catch (SocketException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    wyslijPakiet("\\connect\\" + nickname);
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {                    
                byte[] bufor = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bufor, bufor.length);
                socket.setReuseAddress(true);
                socket.receive(packet);
                String wiadomosc = new String(bufor);
                int finIndex = wiadomosc.indexOf("\\e");
                if(finIndex <= 0)
                    continue;
                wiadomosc = wiadomosc.substring(0, finIndex);
                System.out.println("REC: " + wiadomosc);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

public void wyslijPakiet(String wiadomosc) {
    try {
        wiadomosc += "\\e";
        byte[] dane = wiadomosc.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket pakiet = new DatagramPacket(dane, 0, dane.length, adresKonsultantow, port);
        socket.send(pakiet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void flushText(String text) {
    wyslijPakiet(text);
}
```

}

Comment: Do not call `setReuseAddress` in the while loop: the javadoc states: “The behaviour when SO_REUSEADDR is enabled or disabled after a socket is bound (See isBound()) is not defined.” and it doesn’t make sense anyway if you don’t do it before binding

Comment: When i remove the setReuseAddres method result of the code is the same.